# Repeating background image misaligns at top and bottom margins

Tags: html, css

Go to [unboundsonics.com](http://www.unboundsonics.com) to see it.

At the top of the header and bottom of the footer, you can see the diagonal pinstripes don't line up. Everything is contained in a `<div>` (`<div id="wrap">` to be exact) tag whose margins are automatic horizontally and 15px vertically.

If I change the vertical margins to auto, this problem doesn't occur. Any tips or observations i'm overlooking?

Any help appreciated!

PS: I know my script & styles are a mess but it's a work in progress. I just need to have a rough version for a project due tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem is that you set BG picture for BOTH html and Body, and the body is little smaller, thats why they don't line up.

As a quick fix you can set  bg to apply only to HTML,

But a better would be to set margin  for html and body to 0px, padding for html 0px, and set you padding for body, and apply a bg to body.

**EDIT**

Quickfix:

```
body,html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:#B8C2C9;
background-image:url('bgstripes.png');
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

change to:

```
body,html {
margin:0;
padding:0;
color:#B8C2C9;
}
html {
    background-image:url('bgstripes.png');
}
```

Also note, its not necessary to use background:repeat, as that's the default behaviour

**EDIT2**

Well I would personally do something like this:

```
body,html {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
body{
    background:url(bgstripes.png) #B8C2C9;
    padding:15px 0 15px 0;
}
#wrap {
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#0D1325;
    border:1px outset white;
}
```

Normally we would put a bg to the body, but instead of margins on the container we would better do padding to the parent. Because margins will not necessary pull the height of the container, especially if the parent doesn't have a padding or border. This you can notice in IE7, it would probably collapse the bottom margin.

Comment: If it answered the question, please consider picking it as the answer.

Comment: Hmm i tried to do what you suggested is a better solution but it ended up with the same result. However, the quick fix rocks! Thank you! Could you possibly show me what the better version looks like? I want to learn this nuance so I can prevent it in the future.

PS: I definitely am new to stack overflow so...i'll pick your post as the answer as soon as I figure out how.